# Passport redirect to login page after successful save in DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I have setup Passport with Facebook strategy (just facebook strategy), And set up the check if user exists function to save user in Mongodb within a users collection.
I throw console.log for successful save in DB and I can see that the user has successfully saved in the collection (I can see it also in the DB itself with Terminal.

But the issue is that after successful registration the passport.authenticate function takes me to the login page and not to the 'getusergames' page.
Any Idea why is that?

```
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    // Checking if this user is already in DB and if no, Add this user to DB
    insertUser.findOne({facebook_id: profile.id}, function(err, user) {
        // Print Error
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }
        // Save new user if there is no user exists
        if (!user) {
            var userId = profile.id;
            var userToken = accessToken;
            var user_name = profile.displayName;
            var newuser = new insertUser({
                username: user_name,
                facebook_id: userId,
                facebook_token: userToken
            });
            newuser.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('New User has Saved!');
                    done(null, user);
                }
            });
        }
        // If there is a user, Return his object and done.
        else if (user) {
            done(null, user);
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was that I didn't put `return` before the `done(null, user);`